# UIBezierPath lineWidth based on UIPanGestureRecognizer's velocity

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uibezierpath, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to figure out how to construct a limited range of floating point values based on a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`'s velocity. I have a minimum, or starting value of 1.0, and a maximum of 3.0 to provide a limited range for the `UIBezierPath`'s `lineWidth` property.

I'm trying to figure out how to build an exponential range from 1.0 to 3.0 based accordingly on the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`'s velocity, but am having a difficult time where I should start for mapping the values. The faster the combined x and y velocity, the smaller (down to 1.0) the lineWidth should be, and respectively the opposite up to 3.0 if the combined velocity is slower. I'm also trying to taper/smooth the line width in progress by storing a `lastWidth` property so the transitions aren't noticeable between subpaths.

I'd appreciate any help offered.

Working and final Code based on answer:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat lastWidth;

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view];

    CGFloat absoluteVelocity = 1000.0 / sqrtf(pow(velocity.x, 2) + pow(velocity.y, 2));

    CGFloat clampedVel = MAX(MIN(absoluteVelocity, 3.0), 1.0);

    if (clampedVel > self.lastWidth)
    {
        clampedVel = self.lastWidth + 0.15;
    }
    else if (clampedVel < self.lastWidth)
    {
        clampedVel = self.lastWidth - 0.15;
    }

    self.lastWidth = clampedVel;

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    path.lineWidth = self.lastWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'd use an inverted exponential function.

Start with your velocity, V(x,y). Your absolute velocity is obviously:

```
sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
```

We'll call this value "v."

Next, we want a value that is between 1 and 3 where 1 is the width where "v" is very high and 3 is the width where "v" is very low.

We can calculate that using the following exponential function:

```
- (CGFloat)getExponentialWidthForVeloctity(CGFloat)v {
    if (v <= 1 / 3.0)
        return 3;
    CGFloat inverse = 1 / v;
    return 1 + inverse;
}
```

Or this function that smooths it out a little bit

```
- (CGFloat)getExponentialRootWidthForVeloctity(CGFloat)v {
    //play with this value to get the feel right
    //The higher it is, the faster you'll have to go to get a thinner line
    CGFloat rootConstantYouCanAdjust = 2;
    if (pow(v, rootConstantYouCanAdjust) <= 1 / 3.0)
        return 3;
    CGFloat inverse = 1 / pow(v, rootConstantYouCanAdjust);
    return 1 + inverse;
}
```

If that doesn't feel right, try a linear solution:

```
- (CGFloat)getLinearWidthForVelocity(CGFloat)v {
    //Find this value by swiping your finger really quickly and seeing what the fastest velocity you can get is
    CGFloat myExpectedMaximumVelocity = 1000; 
    if (v > myExpectedMaximumVelocity)
        v = myExpectedMaximumVelocity;
    return 3 - 2 * (v / myExpectedMaximumVelocity);
}
```

And finally, as a bonus, try this sqrt based function that you might find works nicely:

```
- (CGFloat)getSqrtWidthForVelocity(CGFloat)v {
    //find the same way as above
    CGFloat myExpectedMaximumVelocity = 1000;
    if (v > myExpectedMaximumVelocity)
        return 1;
    return 3 - 2 * sqrt(v) / sqrt(myExpectedMaximumVelocity);
}
```

I'd be curious to know which works best! Let me know. I have a lot more functions up my sleeve, these are just some really simple ones that should get you started.

Comment: Alex, will I still need to store a property of the last line width so that I can smooth the line in progress from the last one?

Comment: Also, I tried the four functions you created, only the `getLinearWidthForVelocity` and `getSqrtWidthForVelocity` functions change the line width, which is what I want, the other two functions remain a static size line, even playing with the `rootConstantYouCanAdjust` (set it to 80000) and still didn't change the line width.

Comment: Oops. made a mistake there. Should be 2 / v and 2 / (pow(v, rootConstantYouCanAdjust)) respectively instead of 1 in the numerator.

As for storing the previous value, just use:
@ property (nonatomic) CGFloat previousWidth;

in your @ interface and just reset it every time you call the function that updates the line.

Comment: Also, are those 2 functions returning 3, or some other value? What's probably happening is your "v" is like 10 or something and pow(10, 80000) is equal to "inf" and 2 / "inf" is 0. Thus you always get 1. Use 2 or 2.2 or 2.5 or small values to fiddle with the rootConstantYouCanAdjust

Comment: Alex, the corrected `getExponentialWidth` is returning values in the 1.0 - 1.20 range while moving finger slowly, while the corrected `getExponentialRootWidth` is returning values in the 1.0000 - 1.000133 range or so, even while finger is moving slowly (with the constant being 2.0). Also, I'm not sure I follow you on storing the property. I'm creating a line segment on the gesture state changed state, so I need to find the difference of the last width and the new width and then adjust (taper) it so the segments aren't noticeable. I posted my updated code in my original question.

Comment: Note the multi-line comment in the code in the question. I hope that explains the dilemna well. :)

Comment: shouldn't that code just be:
if (currentVel > self.lastWidth)
    {
        currentVel = self.lastWidth + .1
    }
    else if (currentVel < self.lastWidth)
    {
        currentVel = self.lastWidth - .1
    }

Comment: also, try making the rootConstantYouCanAdjust be < 1. Like .5 or .75 or such.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74972/discussion-between-aviatorken89-and-alexkoren).